# Efficient way to efficiently merge arrays of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the below scenario where I am trying to merge two arrays of objects.

The current code works, but I am looking for a more efficient way.

```js
var constList = [
  { name: "jack", id: "1", designation: "hr" },
  { name: "mary", id: "2", designation: "it" },
  { name: "john", id: "3", designation: "fin" }
]

var apiList = [
  { name: "jack", id: "1", height: "10" },
  { name: "mary", id: "2", height: "20" }
]

var temp = [];

constList.forEach(x => {
  apiList.forEach(y => {
    if (x.id === y.id) {
      temp.push({ ...x,
        ...y
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Are your array ids guaranteed to be sorted sequentially ascending and without gaps as they are in this example?

Comment: They are consecutive but there could be gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this purpose. Group the objects into an aggregate object by some key which we can make a parameter to a function `mergeByKey`. This function takes any number of object arrays which are then flattened (change [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to `[].concat(...objArrs)` for better browser compatibility) then `reduce`d into a single object. During grouping, object spreading updates the value for each unique key as you did. Finally, extract the array of values from the grouping object using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which is the final result.

Time complexity of the original version was `O((n*longest_obj_length)^2)`, but the updated version is `O(n*longest_obj_length)`.

```js
const mergeByKey = (key, ...objArrs) =>
  Object.values(objArrs.flat().reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e[key]] = {...a[e[key]], ...e};
    return a;
  }, {}))
;

const constList = [
  { name: "jack", id: "1", designation: "hr" },
  { name: "mary", id: "2", designation: "it" },
  { name: "john", id: "3", designation: "fin" }
];

const apiList = [
  { name: "jack", id: "1", height: "10" },
  { name: "mary", id: "2", height: "20" }
];

console.log(mergeByKey("id", constList, apiList));
```